# my Void callback function is giving error everytime i call it

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout

**my Void callback function is giving error everytime  i call it.**

1. whenever i press the logout button the error is shown.

```
CustomListTile(Icons.person, 'Profile', () {
  Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ShowDataPage()
    ),
  );
}),
CustomListTile(Icons.text_fields, 'Update My Info.', () {
  Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ProfilePage()
    ),
  );
}),
CustomListTile(Icons.lock_open, 'Log Out',  () {
  widget.onSignedOut();
}),
```

2. This is from where i am calling onSignedOut

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  widget.auth.currentUser().then((userId) {
    setState(() {
      authStatus =
          userId == null ? AuthStatus.notSignedIn : AuthStatus.SignedIn;
    });
  });
}

void _signedIn() {
  setState(() {
    authStatus = AuthStatus.SignedIn;
  });
}

void _signedOut() {
  setState(() {
    authStatus = AuthStatus.notSignedIn;
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  switch (authStatus) {
    case AuthStatus.notSignedIn:
      return new LoginPage(
        auth: widget.auth,
        onSignedIn: _signedIn,
      );
    case AuthStatus.SignedIn:
      return new HomePage(
        auth: widget.auth,
        onSignedOut: _signedOut,
      );
  }
}
```

3. Error is as below

> The method 'call' was called on null.
>
> Receiver: null
>
> Tried calling: call()

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/176s7655EX6hlDgfnu_dP2BV68VOIubDQ?usp=sharing

Comment: Post full code. This is not enough to answer the question.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/176s7655EX6hlDgfnu_dP2BV68VOIubDQ?usp=sharing

Comment: I have added the necessary files in the drive link above.